# Button onclick return false not working

Tags: javascript, html

Html:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-preview" onclick="return functionPrev();">Prev</button>
```

js file:

```
function functionPrev() {
        alert("Alert!");
        return false;
}
```

Alert opens and bootstrap modal opens too, but I only want the alert to show and block modal window.

Answer (score 0):

`data-toggle="modal"` causes Bootstrap to bind a click event listener to this button. Bootstrap's event handler opens the modal. Removing that data attribute should stop this behavior. `data-target="#modal-preview"` will then be unnecessary.

Comment: Ye, but i need to open modal, and if js return false - block the opening.

Comment: Please consult the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modal-show) for interacting with a modal programmatically.